# String column in QGIS shapefile that is read as a factor column in R

Tags: r, attribute-table, sp

I have a shapefile that has 3 columns (ID_1, NAME_1 and Rainfall). The 2nd column contains the names of governorates (type of variable is string).

I have used the sf package in R to read this shapefile and save it in an RDS format, using the code below:

```
TUN_sf <- st_read("Data/TUN_adm/TUN_adm1.shp")
TUN_spdf <- as(TUN_sf, "Spatial")
TUN_sf <- st_as_sf(TUN_spdf)
simp_sf <- ms_simplify(TUN_sf, keep = 0.01, keep_shapes = TRUE)
saveRDS(simp_sf, "simp_sf.rds")
```

However, I noticed that the second column is now considered as a column of factors (even though it was originally a column of string).

I would like to convert this column to string but I don't know how to go about it. I tried simple functions like (as.character) but it distorted the table. This is because the file "simp_sf" is not a simple dataframe but a spatial dataframe (it contains coordinates).

Comment: Are you calling as.character on the whole table or just the column? `simp_sf$NAME_1 <- as.character(simp_sf$NAME_1)` is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help for `st_read` shows:

```
 st_read(dsn, layer, ..., query = NA,
   options = NULL, quiet = FALSE, geometry_column = 1L, type = 0,
   promote_to_multi = TRUE,
   stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors(),
   int64_as_string = FALSE, check_ring_dir = FALSE,
   fid_column_name = character(0))
```

where:

```
stringsAsFactors: logical; logical: should character vectors be
          converted to factors?  The `factory-fresh' default is ‘TRUE’,
          but this can be changed by setting ‘options(stringsAsFactors
          = FALSE)’.
```

A quick test:

```
> sogn = st_read("SOGN.shp", quiet=TRUE)
> class(sogn$DQ_RESPONS)
[1] "factor"
> sogn = st_read("SOGN.shp", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, quiet=TRUE)
> class(sogn$DQ_RESPONS)
[1] "character"
```

Note I don't know why you turn it from an `_sf` object to a `Spatial` object and then back into an `_sf` object though - that should be unnecessary and might cause some other conversions:

```
TUN_sf <- st_read("Data/TUN_adm/TUN_adm1.shp")
TUN_spdf <- as(TUN_sf, "Spatial")
TUN_sf <- st_as_sf(TUN_spdf)
```

Comment: Do you know if `sf_read` honors global settings such as `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`?

Comment: Did you not read my excerpt from the docs? It claims to. A quick test confirms. (And you mean `st_read`? not `sf_read`? (not found))

Comment: The good news is that thanks to your help I was able to ensure that strings are not converted to factors. The bad news is that didn't prove enough to run the rest of my code + About converting from sf to spatial and vice verça: I was trying different functions